# How to extract ONLY numbers from string using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, flow, formula, power-platform

I have free text column in Dataverse table where alphanumeric values are entered e.g. abc123, 123abc, 1abc23. (numbers can be anywhere in string - no fix pattern) I want to extract ONLY  numbers and discard letters using Power Automate.

How to do it? I google a lot but no luck. I found solution here but its not efficient solution at all. Please guide.

Comment: Hi, did you try below solution? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this flow (example):

[image]

It works by creating a do until loop that looks at each character of the string that contains the number. In this case a compose step called “string”. If the character is equal to 0 to 9 or a period then it is appended to the variable called newString, otherwise it is discarded.

Formula used in in the **Append to string variable** action:

```
concat
(
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '0'), '0', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '1'), '1', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '2'), '2', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '3'), '3', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '4'), '4', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '5'), '5', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '6'), '6', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '7'), '7', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '8'), '8', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '9'), '9', ''),
if(equals(substring(outputs('string'), variables('index'), 1), '.'), '.', '')
)
```

**Source**: [Power Automate – How to extract numbers from a string](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/02/power-automate-extract-numbers-from-string)